# Execute .bat from Android gradle

Tags: android, batch-file, android-gradle-plugin

I've been trying to execute a script from gradle. According to the [official page of gradle 2.10](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html) It should be something like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

task testTask(type: Exec){
    println 'This is a test'
    println "The current directory is: "
    workingDir '..'
    println workingDir
    commandLine 'cmd','/c','helloworld.bat'


}

android {...
```

Can anyone tell me why even though the working `dir` is correct, the `.bat`  is not being executed ? or why it is not showing anything on the standard output at least ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to execute the task during a build, you have to tell the Android build process that you depend on this task.

```
preBuild.dependsOn testTask
```

This will call the task before the build starts.

Comment: Can you tell how to execute task after APK was built (for example to sign with manufacturer certificate) ?